Aurelia Slickgrid Tree - Lazy load children on node expansion
I'm considering using Aurelia Slickgrid to display a tree-based data-structure. The data-structure can be very large and should ideally be lazily loaded (as needed) when nodes are expanded by making calls to get the node's children from a back-end service. I originally implemented the UI for this data-structure using Fancytree. However, I'm a bit unsure when it comes to translating my original Fancytree implementation to Aurelia's Tree Data Grid.
I'm not sure whether with the Tree Data Grid I'll be able to lazily load children as the parent nodes are expanded.
I see that in the example documentation you define your data-structure in one of two ways.
Either as a flat structure (with parentId properties helping to define the tree structure):
this.dataset = [
  { id: 0, file: 'documents', parentId: null, },
  { id: 1, file: 'vacation.txt', parentId: 0, },
  { id: 2, file: 'bills.txt', parentId: 0, },
  { id: 55: file: 'music', parentId: null, },
  { id: 60, file: 'favorite-song.mp3', parentId: 55, },
  { id: 61, file: 'blues.mp3', parentId: 61, },
];

or as a hierarchical structure:
this.datasetHierarchical = [
  { id: 0, file: 'documents', files: [
      { id: 1, file: 'vacation.txt', size: 12 },
      { id: 2, file: 'bills.txt', size: 0.5 }
    ]
  },
  { id: 55: file: 'music', files: [
      { id: 60, file: 'favorite-song.mp3': size: 2.3 },
      { id: 61, file: 'blues.mp3', size: 5.5 }
    ]
  },
];

I see there is a section in the documentation where it describes how to provide data to the grid. This part mentions that you can implement your own custom data provider by providing implementations for methods such as getLength(), getItem(index) and getItemMetadata(index). But it seems as though this is only relevant for the flat table based grid (and not the tree grid), if I'm not mistaken?
I'm basically looking for an equivalent of the following logic I could get working with Fancytree:
$("#tree").fancytree({
    checkbox: true,
    selectMode: 3,
    source: fileSystemService.getRoots().then(roots => {
        return roots.map((node) => ({
            title: node.name,
            key: node.path,
            folder: true,
            lazy: true
        }));
    }),
    lazyLoad: function(event, data) {
        const node = data.node;
        data.result = fileSystemService.getChildren(node.key).then(nodes => {
            return nodes.map((node) => ({
                title: node.name,
                key: node.path,
                folder: node.type !== FileSystemService.File,
                lazy: node.type !== FileSystemService.File
            }));
        });
    },
    loadChildren: function(event, data) {
        data.node.fixSelection3AfterClick();
    },
    ...
}

with the abovementioned Fancytree configuration, the root nodes are initialized using the following logic:
source: fileSystemService.getRoots().then(roots => {
...
}),

and any child nodes below those roots (and deeper down) will be lazily loaded on expansion with the following logic:
data.result = fileSystemService.getChildren(node.key).then(nodes => {
...
},

Is there an equivalent of this lazy loading behavior in Arelia Slickgrid (specifically for the Tree Data Grid)?

I really discourage you to create a custom data provider because I don't really support it and Tree Data surely won't work out of the box. SlickGrid doesn't support Tree Data out of the box, so what I did was to keep 2 refs (1 ref for flat dataset & 1 ref for tree dataset) and whenever 1 changes then the 2nd one needs to be resynched (it typically does all of that internally and transparently). If you want to lazy load data, the Tree should automatically resynch with the array push, just don't use any of the Backend Service API because it's not supported and you'll get an error
